# Extract the month from DateField in Django template

Tags: python, django

Want to extract the month and year from template

template_1.html

```
   <form method = 'POST'>
      <input type ='month' name = 'searchmonth'>
      <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'>
   </form>
```

template_2.html

```
   {% for i in record %}
   {% if i.record_patient_number == number %}
   {{ month = i.record_date.getMonth() }}

   {% if month == searchrecordmonth %}
     *something*


   {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

All variable are include in views.py

In this search month is not able to extract and record_date is save in models.py and as a

```
    record_date = models.DateField(blank = True , null = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set values while in django template, your code below is invalid

```
{{ month = i.record_date.getMonth() }}
```

to get the month, simply get it from the i.record_date

```
{% if i.record_date.month == searchrecordmonth %}
```